# Reading numbers from a file and creating an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, filereader, duplicates

I cannot figure out how to make this txt file with numbers into an array, I am able to get it to read and print the screen but I need to be able to organize the numbers and delete the duplicates. This is what my code looks like so far

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class File {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String filename = "C:/input.txt";

 File rfe = new File();
 rfe.readFile(filename);
 }

 private void readFile(String name) {
 String input;

  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name))) {

    while((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.format(input); // Display the line on the monitor
    }
}
 catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

 }
 catch(IOException ioe) {

 }
 catch(Exception ex) { // Not required, but a good practice

 }


}
}
```

Comment: Does the source of the input really matter here? Your question seems to be _[how] to organize the numbers and delete the duplicates_. What have you done to achieve that?

Comment: simply add them to a `Set`. Duplicates will be eliminated automatically

Comment: Arrays aren't dynamic data structures in Java, so you can't "remove elements". What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an ArrayList rather than an Array.

With an array you would have to parse through the list and calculate the line count before you could even initialize it. An ArrayList is much more flexible as you don't have to declare how many values will be added to it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class File {

private List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Create ArrayList

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "C:/input.txt";

    File rfe = new File();
    rfe.readFile(filename);
}

private void readFile(String name) {
    String input;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name))) {

        while((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            data.add(Integer.parseInt(input));//Add each parsed number to the arraylist
            System.out.println(input); // Display the line on the monitor
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {

    }
    catch(Exception ex) { // Not required, but a good practice
        ex.printstacktrace(); //Usually good for general handling
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the process of teaching myself how to code so this was really helpful!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!